# Trouble with precision, point accuracy at intersection of 3 planes

Tags: c++, precision, intersection, algebra, plane

have tried multiple methods of plane intersection, the code is not producing an accurate result. At some angles its pretty good, for a right angle triangle, roughly in position but noticeably off.

```
xyzPoint return_Intersect_3planes(Tri tri1, Tri tri2, Tri tri3) {

double x1 =  0.646;
double y1 =  0.210;
double z1 =  2.147;
double a1 =  0.251;
double b1 =  -0.456;
double c1 = -0.411;
double d1 = -((a1 * x1) + (b1 * y1) + (c1 * z1));

double x2 = -0.0744;
double y2 = 0.0808;
double z2 = 2.082;
double a2 = -0.1218;
double b2 = -0.2606;
double c2 = -0.748;
double d2 = -((a2 * x2) + (b2 * y2) + (c2 * z2));

double x3 = 0.10627;
double y3 = 0.3924;
double z3 = 2.335;
double a3 = 0.0987;
double b3 = 0.3236;
double c3 = -0.278;
double d3 = -((a3 * x3) + (b3 * y3) + (c3 * z3));


double D =  (a2 * b2 * c3) + (b1 * c2 * a3) + (c1 * a2 * b3) - (a3 * b2 * c1) - (b3 * c2 * a1) - (c3 * a2 * b1);
double Dx = (d1 * b2 * c3) + (b1 * c2 * d3) + (c1 * d2 * b3) - (d3 * b2 * c1) - (b3 * c2 * d1) - (c3 * d2 * b1);
double Dy = (a1 * d2 * c3) + (d1 * c2 * a3) + (c1 * a2 * d3) - (a3 * d2 * c1) - (d3 * c2 * a1) - (c3 * a2 * d1);
double Dz = (a1 * b2 * d3) + (b1 * d2 * a3) + (d1 * a2 * b3) - (a3 * b2 * d1) - (b3 * d2 * a1) - (d3 * a2 * b1);



xyzPoint Intersection;
Intersection.x = Dx / D;
Intersection.y = Dy / D;
Intersection.z = Dz / D;


return Intersection;
```

}

[The input numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNadQ.png)

Result is

x = 0.00276579 y = -0.32880155 z = -4.0193058
(this has been flipped to negative and might be totally wrong?)

Correct position based on CAD is

x = -0.002 y = 0.204 z = 2.498

ODS (open office calc) file has been uploaded
https://filebin.net/g6onuah7q5rfg7lj

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including the input, output, and expected output

Comment: Please, create a complete compilable example including input data at best, such that one can compile and run it. No one will be likely willing to help you if you force them to retype numbers from some image.

Comment: Is there a way I can attach an excel file?

Comment: @shs125 Upload it to an online storage ([Google Drive](https://drive.google.com), [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/), [Mega](https://mega.nz/)) and share the link.

Comment: Lilnking externally to helpful data is not ideal. Prefer to use the data for making a [mre] which does not require input, i.e. hardcode the data into suitable data structure initialisations, then use them in the code to demonstrate what you describe.

Comment: Or, export to a `.csv` file and paste the contents here.

Comment: Please study and apply the concept of making a [mre].

Comment: There that should be compilable... thanks for the tips and got rid of a lot of junk while at it... using only first vertex of each of the 3 triangles and included normals.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, I am getting completely different numbers for your code: https://godbolt.org/z/7as9MhjKf. Please, share code that matches your wrong output.

Comment: So sorry, its late Im tired, wrong numbers have been revised.

Comment: `double D =  (a2 * b2 * c3)...` looks wrong, duplicating index 2.

Comment: Hi Nordic, that did it, that had me hung up for a week... send you ten bucks lol